# Read only SQL.. Are there any DSL around?

Tags: python, sql, django, dsl

We want to give some of our users permissions to read from database whatever they want, so we're interested - are there any SQL dialect that supports only SELECT, WHERE and JOIN operators?

We want to use it like this:

```
class MyModelWithSQLRule(models.Model):
    sql_rule = models.TextField()

    def what_data_i_will_get(self): 
        """
        Here we must get exception with attempt of query like
        DELETE * FROM users_users; SELECT id FROM users_users; 
        """
        parsed_sql_rule = select_only_parser(self.sql_rule)
        return Users.objects.raw(parsed_sql_rule)
```

It's not about database engine. I want **language**, that in sub-family of SQL, but don't have dangerous words like `DELETE`.

Comment: Do it with permissions in your database engine!

Comment: Depending on what database you use there's a lot of different answers  "How To", so what database are you using and are you using a OR-M or not?

Comment: Which SQL Database are you using?  Different databases support different mechanisms for access control.

Comment: "read from database whatever they want". This sounds like a dangerous and/or limiting design... A practical example would be useful to help shape the solution

Comment: Why do you need to Database Access control in your DSL rather than using the control provided by your DB?

Comment: @JaimalChohan "It requires db administration, or more than one connection to db. I just want to check that query is sanitized." read the comments in the answer below.

Comment: @JeffWatkins, it really depends what Nikolays application is supposed to do as to whether it is dangerous/limiting. For all we know it could be an in-house tool to be used by people experienced in writing SQL to get data out of the database and limiting the vocabulary is just to stop people doing silly things accidentally.

Comment: @KevinBrydon which is still no reason not to use permissions.

Comment: @podiluska I agree that permissions are probably the easiest answer but Nikolay has stated that he does not want to use them. Probably because he does not want to modify the database/server just to query it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what you've said, the answer is No.

What you could do is have 2 Connection Strings for your database, 1 which is set at the DB level to be readonly, the other could be a read/write connection string, then you just need to construct a database session context with the appropriate connection string.  This gives you a level of percieved security at your application level, but ultimately still relies on the DB as errors will be thrown from there.

Comment: Actually I accept for now, that the is answer is No, there is no sub-language of SQL that oriented to read-only operations. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most SQL implementations will allow you to control access and rights using permissions, typically with keywords such as `GRANT`, `DENY` and `REVOKE`

Comment: +1, use the built-in access control

Comment: No no no.. It requires db administration, or more than one connection to db. I just want to check that query is sanitized. I know about `GRANT` - it's not for this task. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the database to do the authorization, I think you'll have to move the problem to the programming language utilizing SQL. I know of no SQL dialect that you could use that would only allow non-modifying queries.

What about you just parse your expressions and see if it makes use of any forbidden keywords, like DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT etc. Parsing (a large subset of) SQL is very doable in Python, I'd suggest you look into that instead. *Though I still think that it would be cleaner and easier to make a read-only user and pass all queries through a separate connection.*

EDIT:

Maybe you could use transactions but never commit them? Would that work for you?

Comment: I have thought about making something like `if ['UPDATE', 'DELETE', 'INSERT'] in query` and after starting this solution - decided to ask about sub-language of SQL. There are limited sql dsl for scala - https://github.com/p3t0r/scala-sql-dsl - I want something like this for python.

Comment: I'd recommend thinking again if you are going to use a simple `if [...] in query` approach. Setting yourself up for a whole world of pain. Forgetting about malicious users for one moment, what if someone were to construct a perfectly legitimate `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Status = 'DELETE';`. I think you're now facing the challenge of building your own SQL parser or hooking into an existing one ... good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, if all you need to support is django - is to write your own database adapter that filters your queries for you.

This will allow you to create your own "sql dialect".